# Code to delete table row in database won't work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete a row in a table in my database, but it isn't working... The connection works. I've echoed the table row id to ensure it is working and still it won't delete...

Let me know if you need the connection code too.

code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Recent Posts</td>
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone number']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="delete2.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">Schedule</a></td>
  </tr>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

delete.php code:

```
  <?php
    $b=$_GET['id'];
    $sql='DELETE FROM on call WHERE id=$b';
//echoing just to make sure it is working correctly...
echo $b;
    ?>
    </br>
    </br>
    <a href='index2.php'>back to list</a>
```

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: What is your table called? If it's `on call`, you'll need to wrap it in backticks. (And I'd suggest renaming it so it doesn't have a space in the name).

Comment: What is your table????

Comment: Always "on the ball" ;-) @andrewsi

Answer (score 3):

You didn't execute your DELETE sql command using **mysql_query**

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM ...";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Please note that the **mysql** functions are now deprecated. Also, you should protect your code against SQL injections.

Comment: I executed my sql and it still doesn't work... Is this because it is deprecated??

Comment: I can't help when someone just tells me "it doesn't work". what is the error message for example?

Comment: Sorry. I added the query to execute the DELETE sql command. I don't get any error messages though... You can try it yourself if you like:

[link]http://andadietcoke.com/test/index2.php[/link]

I'm also echoing the table row id number at the moment just to make sure the correct number is being passed to the delete.php... Thanks!

Comment: use this instead:
$sql='DELETE FROM on call WHERE id=' . $b;

Comment: well actually it's impossible that your table is called "on call", there should be no white space (sorry, when I commented I copy/pasted and didn't see this detail).

Comment: I've renamed the table to `on_call`

Comment: put this in the very beginning of your script: error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

Comment: well then the DELETE is executing

Comment: Why is it not deleting the row from the table though? When I reload the page with the table, the row isn't deleted...

Comment: you should repost your DELETE query

Comment: 'code' <body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);
$b=$_GET['id'];
$sql='DELETE FROM `on_call` WHERE id=' . $b;
mysql_query($sql,$con);
?>
</br>
</br>
<a href='index2.php'>back to list</a>
</body>

Comment: you should set error_reporting and ini_set at the very beginning of your file. Anyway, everything seems ok o me with he code above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your sql syntax. if 'on call' is your table, please rename your table to **on_call** and so your sql should :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM on_call WHERE id = '" . $b . "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not execute your sql.
mysql_query($sql); use mysql function to prevent injection.

Comment: I added a query to execute the sql... I'm not getting any error messages and it still isn't working...

Also, how do I prevent injection?